# Rails: best practices for maintaining a list of ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm still new to rails so I apologize in advance if this question is basic.

I want a user to be able to choose some fixed number of rows from another table as their "favorite" elements in that table. Currently, the way I have implemented this is to add n integer columns to the user model. These integers will function as foreign keys into another table, from which the user selects favorites. These columns will default to 0. When users edit (add or remove) favorites, the code will have to iterate through these elements and reset them accordingly.

Is there a better way to implement this functionality? I don't think it can be implemented using active record associations. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know about `has_and_belongs_to_many` (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets assume that you have models [User and Item], where the User can Favourite an Item.
Since the relation is bidirectional, (the user can favourite many items) and (item can be favourited by multiple uses). So we will use `has_and_belongs_to_many` association.

We will create a table `users_favourite_items` that includes the tuple rows of data ex: [user1_id, item1_id]

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users,
      :association_foreign_key => 'user_id',
      :class_name => 'User',
      :join_table => 'users_favourite_items'
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :items,
    :association_foreign_key => 'item_id',
    :class_name => 'Item',
    :join_table => 'users_favourite_items'
end
Then need to create new users_favourite_items migration like below.

class CreateUsersFavouriteItemsTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table : users_favourite_items, :id => false do |t|
      t.references :item
      t.references :user
    end
    add_index :users_favourite_items, [:item_id, :user_id]
    add_index :users_favourite_items, [:user_id, :item_id]
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :users_favourite_items
  end
end
```

Comment: That `:join_table => 'users_favourite_items'` in both models(user and item) is unnecessary and should be avoided unless you have a very good reason to create a table named `users_favourite_items`, only if table name was `items_users`, everything will work without an extra effort. That's why Rails is convention over configuration.

Comment: You are right, i'd prefere has_many through myself. This example was just to give him clear idea of how they are connected.